Google ID Token Invalid Only When Using Sign In With Google Button
I am working on implementing Sign In With Google functionality for my website. The ID tokens are being verified in Python, using the verify_oauth2_token function from the google.oauth2 library. This Python script is hosted as a web service on a separate server from the server responsible for hosting the login page, and the token is sent between the two by serializing it to JSON and UTF8 encoding it before sending it via POST request. The verification works consistently in a test environment, but upon moving to our production environment, the function has been returning "Invalid Token" for users who have valid tokens in the test environment. Even stranger, the tokens are only coming back invalid when using the Sign In With Google button; using the One Tap sign-in method works consistently in both environments.
I have tried looking at the ID tokens, expecting to see some obvious issue with them, such as being truncated or formatted incorrectly. However, the tokens are formatted the same as the valid tokens I have observed. I've been unable to determine any difference in how tokens are received or processed that would explain why this issue only affects the Sign In button, and not the One Tap sign in.
